# SSL verification fails for socket in python3.9 and working fine in python3.6

Tags: ssl-certificate, python-3.9

I am facing below error after upgrade to python3.9 from python3.6
**[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)**
Below one is code snippet, here at **ssl.wrap_socket** if we use cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
I am facing ssl verification fail error but working fine with Python3.6 version.
So, I need help to fix this error with python3.9.

```
     def add_ssl_verification(sock, server_side=False, server_hostname=None, with_sni=False, use_2048bit_certs=False):
        def get_certs():
            # We have our own certificates which we return here

            return server_cert, server_key, peer_cert, peer_key, ca_cert

        def wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None,
                        server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                       ciphers=None, server_hostname=None):

            # this method comes from ssl.py
            # I only modified one line to enable SNI (that OpenShift requires to accept TLS over its routes)

            if server_side and not certfile:
                raise ValueError("certfile must be specified for server-side "
                                 "operations")
            if keyfile and not certfile:
                raise ValueError("certfile must be specified")
            context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl_version)
            context.verify_mode = cert_reqs
            if ca_certs:
                context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
            if certfile:
                context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
            if ciphers:
                context.set_ciphers(ciphers)
            return context.wrap_socket(
                sock=sock, server_side=server_side,
                do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
                suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
                server_hostname=server_hostname  # added to enable SNI
            )

        certs = get_certs()
        ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 if hasattr(ssl, 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2') else ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23
        if with_sni:
            return wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=certs[3], certfile=certs[2], server_side=server_side,
                               ca_certs=certs[4], ssl_version=ssl_version, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                               do_handshake_on_connect=not server_side, server_hostname=server_hostname)
        else:
            return ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=certs[3], certfile=certs[2], server_side=server_side,
                                   ca_certs=certs[4], ssl_version=ssl_version, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                   do_handshake_on_connect=not server_side)
```

I am expecting the solution to fix this error with python3.9 and I need to know why it is failing in ptyhon3.9 and same code is working with python3.6 version.